# How to insert values into the following table by incrementing the date column by 1 day for the next 23 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have a table names `T1` (extract shown below):

```
Company     ReviewDate    Rank     Type       Reviews
  ...
  A         2020-10-12    8        Hotel      675
  B         2020-10-12    10       Hotel      450 
  C         2020-10-12    21       Hotel       89
  D         2020-10-12    60       Hotel      1200
  A         2020-10-13    5        Hotel      688
  B         2020-10-13    10       Hotel      500 
  C         2020-10-13    21       Hotel       89
  D         2020-10-13    60       Hotel      1200
```

I need to update table `T1` for period `2020-10-13` to `2020-11-04` with the following logic: All rows to be appended to the table will have the same values as those for `ReviewDate` on `2020-10-12` except the `ReviewDate` which will increment by 1 day until `2020-11-04` is reached.

So here is an extract of how the final table will look like (only appended ReviewDate 2020-10-13 shown:

```
    Company     ReviewDate   Rank      Type     Reviews
      ...
      A         2020-10-11    8        Hotel      675
      B         2020-10-11    10       Hotel      450 
      C         2020-10-11    21       Hotel       89
      D         2020-10-11    60       Hotel      1200 
      A         2020-10-12    5        Hotel      688
      B         2020-10-12    10       Hotel      500 
      C         2020-10-12    21       Hotel       89
      D         2020-10-12    60       Hotel      1200
      A         2020-10-13    5        Hotel      688
      B         2020-10-13    10       Hotel      500 
      C         2020-10-13    21       Hotel       89
      D         2020-10-13    60       Hotel      1200 
      ...
```

NOTE: the table also contain entries with ReviewDate **before** `2020-10-12` but I just need to insert values into the table for a specific period with data related to `2020-10-12`

How can I do that with a `T-SQL` query?

Comment: You say the table needs to be updated, and that the rows need to be "appended", which are some what conflicting. "Updating" the table implies an `UPDATE`, however, "appending" implies adding new rows (an `INSERT`). Are you after an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` here?

Comment: I am after an INSERT

Comment: @Larnu Question title edited to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert rows.  One method is to cross join to the dates you want and use that:

```
insert into t1 (Company, ReviewDate, Rank, Type, Reviews)
    select t1.Company, v.date, t1.Rank, t1.Type, t1.Reviews
    from t1 cross join
         (values ('2020-10-13'),  ('2020-10-14'), . . .
         ) v(date
    where t1.reviewdate = '2020-10-12';
```

There are other ways to create the dates.  One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2020-10-13') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2020-11-04'
     )
select . . .
from t1 cross join
     dates d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (
    COMPANY VARCHAR(1),
    ReviewDate Date,
    [Rank] int
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('A','2020-10-11',5)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('B','2020-10-11',10)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('C','2020-10-11',21)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES  ('D','2020-10-11',60)

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT * FROM @TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COMPANY,
    dateadd(day,1,ReviewDate),
    [Rank]
from CTE
WHERE ReviewDate <= '2020-10-13'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY 2,1
```